# Is there a way to tell Blue Ocean that build descriptions are html?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

We're generally switching from using Freestyle to pipeline projects, and as part of that are using Blue Ocean on a regular basis. For the classic view, we generate html job descriptions that point back, for example, to merge requests in the gitlab server we use. The same build descriptions on Blue Ocean are treated as text, and are virtually useless.

Is there some way of telling Blue Ocean to treat the build descriptions as html or similar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible at the moment.
See [JENKINS-45719](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45719)

Comment: From the comments there: as a workaround you can install the chrome extension that converts the description. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blue-ocean-description-ht/maahpenodjcdhodbonmdkfgnceddigae